# Administrator permission required to rename/create/delete directory on Desktop

Tags: windows-7, permissions, administrator

I use `Home`user which is Administrator account on Windows7. Everytime I want to rename folder on desktop it asks me to give administrator rights.

When I want to save a file on Desktop I can't because it needs Administrator permission. How to remove that?

Comment: This behavior indicates your Windows installation is corrupt.  The best solution would be to install Windows 7 again.

Comment: What are the permissions on the desktop folder?

Comment: Log on with the Home user, open a [command prompt](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/command-prompt-faq#1TC=windows-7), type or paste the following command, and press Enter: `icacls %userprofile%` Then post here the output.

Answer (score 0):

This happen to me on a brand new installation of windows 8.1 pro. Your Windows installation is not corrupt, it is just a bug.

1. In *User Account Settings* in control panel, create a new *temporary*
   user with Administrator privileges. If Windows 8 or above, I suggest you
   create a local account since it is only temporary.
2. Login to the *temporary* account, and set your original Administrator account to standard, then set it back again to Administrator. Logout of the *temporary* account, and log back in to your original Administrator account.
3. The problem should be solved. You can delete the *temporary* account that you created.

**Note:** When I logged out, my original account was not set to Administrator. It just needed to be reset.

**desktop.ini** If you see two desktop.ini files, just remember to *Hide Protected Operating System Files* in folder view options.